# Recursion and Optimal Outcomes - Python

Tags: python, recursion, optimization, binary-search-tree

I've hit a comprehension wall with respect to the following code.  It is intended to search through a list of items that have both a personal utility and a cost, as if it is looking for an optimal solution in a binary search tree of possible items. Specifically, it contemplates the maximum utility that can be obtained by combining the items, subject to a weight constraint that is passed into the function.

The first recursive call under the else statement is where the trouble starts.   Once the initial recursive call is made, and values are thrown into  withVal and withToTake, does the code continue to recurse - piling up stack frames until a base case is hit - or does it continue to the bottom of the code and then consider the recursive calls? Print statements were of no help on this one. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

```
def maxVal(toConsider, avail):
    '''Assumes toConsider is a list of items (nodes higher up in the tree
       corresponding to earlier calls in the recursive stack. That have not
       yet been considered. avail a weight (amt of space still available).
       Returns a tuple of the total value of a solution to the 0/1
       knapsack problem and the items of that solution.
       *Note we are NOT building the search tree.  The local variable
       result returns the best result found so far.To be used with
       food class*
    '''
    #Base Cases: Nothing left to consider, or available weight is 0
    if toConsider == [] or avail == 0:
        result = (0, ())
    #look at the first item's weight in toConsider & check against available space
    #if the item's weight is > avail, recurse and slice off the first item
    elif toConsider[0].getCost() > avail:
        result = maxVal(toConsider[1:], avail)
    else:
        #look at left branch
        nextItem = toConsider[0]
        **withVal, withToTake = maxVal(toConsider[1:], avail - nextItem.getCost())**
        withVal += nextItem.getValue()
        #look at right branch
        withoutVal, withoutToTake = maxVal(toConsider[1:], avail)
        #tests whether left or right branch is better
        if withVal > withoutVal:
            result = (withVal, withToTake + (nextItem,))
        else:
            result = (withoutVal, withToTake)
    return result
```

toCosider would take a list of Food objects with utility values & maxUnits is an arbitrary integer indicating the maximum amount of food one can carry.

Comment: You could benefit from memoization: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization

Comment: You are absolutely correct. However, before going there, I probably ought to thoroughly investigate what is happening here.

Comment: At the point in the code where a recursive call is made, at that point you spawn a new stack frame. You don't proceed to the next line of code until that call terminates, which will involve recursing until basis cases are hit. Why doesn't print help? You could add a depth parameter (which defaults to 0) and with each call print the depth, incrementing it before you call the function again. The printed depths should give you an idea of what is happening.

Comment: @JohnColeman - Many thanks! Was unaware of the depth parameter.

Comment: Your brute force function worked for me on a small data set (N=3). It is depth first, and can't exceed depth N. (or N+1 if you count the empty base case call) The only problem is that this is not supposed to work on a decent sized data set, which is why we study knapsack problems.

Comment: Thanks @KennyOstrom! The code is good, and running it in a visual debugger is helping me get where I need to be, but there seem to be unusual jumps when processing a small data set and making assignments. Part of the issue is that variables withVal and withToTake (aside from the confusing assignment syntax -- new one on me) don't appear in the environment until after all recursive calls have been made, but I'll get there. Again, many thanks for the reply!

Comment: If your own **print** statements didn't help, you might want to adapt the instrumentation I suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40269260/recursion-done-inside-of-a-variable/40269704#40269704).

Comment: @Prune Thanks for the reference! I will certainly have a look. Things are coming together, albeit slowly. Learning more nuances of recursion, new stuff about assignment since, in this case, it's coupled with recursion, & how to think about the underlying tree without actually seeing it.